# Mousemove Event not firing on Iiyama Multi Touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Iiyama PCAP Multi Touch Monitor on which I want to listen for the mousemove (touchmove) event. But this event is never triggered on this monitor. Is there a chance to get the following working, or any other idea for what I must listen on such devices?

```
$(this).on("mousemove", function () {
    hasMoved = true;
    lastMove = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (isidle) {
      onactive.call(this);
      isidle = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `this`, it is pointing to the correct HTML element to attach the event? `mousemove` doesn't listen `touchmove`, you need a separate listener for `touchmove`.

Comment: The element is correct. I also tried `on("mousemove touchmove")` - but makes no difference, not working on the touch?

Comment: Does the device listen any touch events? Ex. `click` should be able to be triggered by tapping the element too.

Comment: I think you where right, the device is listening, I tried the touchend and it worked. I am listening to the body because I would like to track if idle status and redirect to the homepage if the device is not in use anymore (kiosk system). But the tracking is a little bit confusing, the events are only fired if I click on an area where also html is shown. For example I have a Headline and at the bottom of the headline there is many blank space on the screen. The events are only fired if I touch on the headline? Don't understand this ...

Comment: Thanks, document is the solution.

Comment: `body` element covers only the area which has some visible content. Listen on `document` instead. Or maybe [capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) or [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) of `window` to detect when user leaves it.

Answer (score 0):

You tried the touche-events?

```
$(this).on("touchmove", function () {
    hasMoved = true;
    lastMove = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (isidle) {
      onactive.call(this);
      isidle = false;
    }
});
```

More touch-events here: [touch events](https://flaviocopes.com/touch-events/)

Comment: mousemove === touchmove - it should be exact the same thing?